# Firefox in Ubuntu 19.10 uses its own mouse pointers

Tags: firefox, mouse, snap, 19.10

Snap Firefox in Ubuntu 19.10 uses its own mouse pointers rather than customized Ubuntu mouse pointers.

I had customized Ubuntu to have a bigger mouse pointer, but when mouse pointer was moved to/over a Firefox window, the pointer changed size back to small, then back to large when moved off a Firefox window.

Comment: Follow this bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/snapd/+bug/1585332